# ModuleNotFoundError - import in Python while running uvicorn is not being resolved

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I do have simple [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) app and I have used **pip** and **venv** to manage environment. When I run it via uvicorn installed package my import is not visible. It works in python terminal.

**simplified folder structure:**
/venv
/src
main.py
..
requirements.txt
..

**requirements.txt**

```
alembic==1.4.3
click==7.1.2
fastapi==0.61.1
FastAPI-SQLAlchemy==0.2.1
pydantic==1.6.1
SQLAlchemy==1.3.20
uvicorn==0.12.2
python-dotenv==0.14.0
```

In python shell after I will activate environment importing fastapi_sqlalchemy works:

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Aug 25 2020, 14:19:38) 
[Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import fastapi_sqlalchemy
>>>
```

But when I will run fastapi via uvicorn the app will throw error on **fastapi_sqlalchemy** import.

```
uvicorn src.main:app --reload                                                                                                                                                                                                     ✔  16:58:54
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [40567] using statreload
3.8.5 (default, Aug 25 2020, 14:19:38) 
[Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)]
Process SpawnProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
(... stacktrace here ...)

 File "./src/main.py", line 8, in <module>
import fastapi_sqlalchemy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastapi_sqlalchemy'
```

**src/main.py**

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from dotenv import load_dotenv

import sys
print(sys.version)

import fastapi_sqlalchemy
```

I do not know how to make this library visible into context of running uvicorn/fastapi app.

Comment: How does uvicorn know to use the virtual environment?

Comment: I did assumed it does run in a context of the terminal runtime that should use venv. Therefore I expected It will see import as I can refer in python shell.

Comment: How did you enable the environment?

Comment: Not sure what you have in mind Peter. I did run source venv/bin/activate but not sure it bring more context as I said - I dont have problem when I run import in python shell.

Comment: Hmmm go to the same folder with src and run it like `src.main:app`

Comment: This is exactly how i run it :(

Answer (score 4):

In the end... I did restarted my computer and it worked ‍♂️

Thank everyone who took a look into this one.

Answer (score -6):

```
import fastapi_sqlalchemy
```

should be

```
import FastAPI-SQLAlchemy
```